# Multibootusb - Trinity Rescue Kit not working

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, iso-image

What I would like to do: I would like to setup a multi-boot usb using multibootusb. It shall include Trinity-Rescue and a few other iso's.

The problem: Multiple iso fail to start when installing them via multibootusb or throw an error. For example Trinity-Rescue doesn't boot.

My question: What are the proper steps to investigate why Trinity-Rescue doesn't boot and what can I change so it does boot? (if it is possible to say - I will add additional information as soon as I have somewhere to start)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I got around the error which was "not a COM32R image" and run into "can't find trk medium". When I tried to fix this by mounting the trk medium it threw me an error cause of the ntfs file-system. I assume now that it doesn't run on ntfs.